# pyModbus client send and recieve data

Tags: python, python-3.x, modbus

i want use pymodbus to implement Modbus Client/Server .
this is the server code:

```
import argparse
from pyModbusTCP.server import ModbusServer
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # parse args
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-H', '--host', type=str, default='localhost', help='Host')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=502, help='TCP port')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # start modbus server
    print('Starting Modbus Server ...')
    time.sleep(2)
    server = ModbusServer(host=args.host, port=args.port)
    server.start()
```

how can i write a client and transmit simple data between server and client?

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/pyModbusTCP/ contains a few nice examples, e.g.: http://pythonhosted.org/pyModbusTCP/examples/modbus_thread.html

Comment: i still don't know how to  work  with this